# Jquery Fancybox Error

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've been updating a site and have used the fancybox plug in to display dynamic information data.  Works great in every browser apart from IE, where i get 'object doesnt support this property or method' errors.   I cant figure out why, it's driving me nuts.  has anyone else expereinced this with IE?  Any hints/tips?

I'm using this function -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js"> </script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickInfo").fancybox({
        'overlayShow':          true,
        'autoScale':            false,
        'transitionIn':         'elastic',
        'transitionOut':        'elastic'
})});; 
</script>
```

called by this -

```
<a href="CTDef.asp?ind=<%=(Names.Fields.Item("Indicator").Value)%>"    class="clickInfo">click for more info</a>
```

Comment: you should post your code too.

Comment: I'm using Fancybox in IE 8.0.6 without issue.

Comment: Without real not working code, it will be hard to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've had this error in IE in the past, it's been because an ID on the page was the same as one of the function names.